# tidyr - nesting_ alternatives

Tags: r, tidyr

I am looking for way to replace `nesting_` in my code as I saw the function is marked as `Deprecated lifecycle`.

Here is sample code where I used `nesting_` in `complete` to passing a vector of columns' names and generate all possible combination between column `a` and pairs `b` & `c`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data <- tibble(a = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3),
  b = c("P-1", "P-2", "P-3", "P-2", "P-4"),
  c = c("O-1", "O-4", "O-2", "O-3", "O-3"))


# 
nesting_variables <- c("b", "c", "c")
data %>%
  complete(a, nesting_(unique(nesting_variables)))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 15 x 3
       a b     c    
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 1     1 P-1   O-1  
 2     1 P-2   O-3  
 3     1 P-2   O-4  
 4     1 P-3   O-2  
 5     1 P-4   O-3  
 6     2 P-1   O-1  
 7     2 P-2   O-3  
 8     2 P-2   O-4  
 9     2 P-3   O-2  
10     2 P-4   O-3  
11     3 P-1   O-1  
12     3 P-2   O-3  
13     3 P-2   O-4  
14     3 P-3   O-2  
15     3 P-4   O-3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nesting` instead with `syms` and `!!!` :

```
library(tidyr)
library(rlang)

data %>% complete(a, nesting(!!!syms(unique(nesting_variables))))
```

---

We can confirm that both the solutions give the same output :

```
identical(data %>% complete(a, nesting(!!!syms(unique(nesting_variables)))), 
          data %>% complete(a, nesting_(unique(nesting_variables))))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Reference to understand the mechanism - [link](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#unquoting)